# Uninitialized reference in C++ (declared using extern)

Tags: c++, reference, extern

I am not able to explain why the following code construct in C++ is not giving any compilation errors or warnings even with -Wall option.

Say there is a header file, referencesTest.hpp, where a reference to int is declared using extern like so :

```
#ifndef REFERENCES_TEST_HPP
#define REFERENCES_TEST_HPP

extern int &refToInt;

#endif /* REFERENCES_TEST_HPP */
```

In the corresponding source file, referencesTest.cpp, we then have the reference defined but is left uninitialized and we try to assign it a value at run time like so:

```
#include "referencesTest.hpp"

//Why no error/warning is raised here ?
int &refToInt;

int main()
{
        int testVariable = 8;

        //This crashes on run time with Seg fault but no compilation error/warnings.
        refToInt = testVariable;

        return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC version 5.4.0

```
g++ -Wall referencesTest.cpp -o output
```

it crashes with segmentation fault at run time but why did compiler not raise any errors/warning here?
My understating was that references in C++ always need to initialized when they are declared. 
Can someone help explain why the above code compilers ?

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior. Different compilers will have different ways of dealing with this. For example, Visual Studio did raise an error when I tried to do what you did.

Comment: Hi Devin .. Thanks for your reply ! Is this mentioned some where in the standard ?

Comment: The standard imposes no requirements when it comes to undefined behavior. Sorry I can't refer you to the actual documentation since it costs money to acquire. I just know this fact from various posts on Stack Overflow.